# How can you write a security rule to ensure that a user can write to a cloud firestore document only once?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am creating a polling app using firebase, and I need to write down a security rule that allows a user to write to a document only once. I thought of creating a list of user ids of users who have written to the document and then create a rule that checks if a new request is from a user who has already cast his vote. But, the trouble is that I will have to create such a list of users from the client-side which is not safe. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: *"the trouble is that I will have to create such a list of users from the client-side which is not safe"* - sure it is safe.  Your security rule can check to see if the user's uid has or has not already been used to write a document, as long as you place limits on how the user writes their own UID.

Comment: @DougStevenson Isn't is possible for the user to write to the document storing his votes but not write to the list. I can't think of a way to ensure that he always does add his uid to the list.

Comment: If your rule requires that the user add their name to the list (by comparing the before and after values of the list), or even create another document as part of the batch/transaction, then it will be enforced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enforce via a rule that when a user write to the doc he also has to add himself to the list. Simple example:

```
match /docs/{docid} {
  allow update: if userNotInList() && userAddedToList()
    && ... // Add more conditions as needed
  
  function userNotInList() {
    return !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/docs/$(docid)/userlist/$(request.auth.uid));
  }
  function userAddedToList() {
    return existsAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/docs/$(docid)/userlist/$(request.auth.uid));
  }
  match /userlist/{userid} {
    allow create: if userid == request.auth.uid
      && request.resource.data.time == request.time  // For instance
      && ... // Add more conditions as needed
}
```

And you have to write both documents in a batch